# android delete old cache data programmatically

Tags: java, android, file, caching

I'm using android disk cache to cache all images loaded from server.

I want to delete all those cache images that has not been used for atleast 2 weeks and keep the remaining.

Here's my code to add cache Images

```
public void addBitMaptoCache(String key,Bitmap bmp)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Cache Creation Running");

    if(null != defaultBitmaps){
        for(Bitmap dbmp:defaultBitmaps){
            if(dbmp.sameAs(bmp)){
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    if(directory!=null)
    {

        if(!directory.exists())
        {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        if(directory.exists())
        {
            if(directory.isDirectory())
            {

                File destination = new File(directory, key + ".jpg");

                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                destination = new File(directory, key + ".jpg");

                if(destination.exists())
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cache Created");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cache not Created");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome... let me know if you need any more details...

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: actually in my scenario an image is required by the app for only some weeks, after that period the image may not be required by the app at all, so these needs to be deleted.

Comment: why don't you use the Volley with LurCache, the LurCache will handle the caching machenisum for you, and you can also set the amount of data to cache in LurCache using Volley.
Refer this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: LruCache is used to cache data/image in memory, it may get deleted after app restart. Whereas I want to keep them after app restart as well. So LruCache is not an option.  @PravinsinghWaghela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the help of last modified date of files.
The following code may help.

```
if(cacheDir.isDirectory()){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();

        for(File file:files){
            if(null != file){


                long lastModified = file.lastModified();

                if (0 < lastModified) {
                    Date lastMDate = new Date(lastModified);
                    Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

                    if (null != lastMDate && null != today) {
                        long diff = today.getTime() - lastMDate.getTime();
                        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        if (15 < diffDays) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

This code will delete cached files that are older than 15 days.